# iPad like scrolling in Windows Explorer and other apps, feasible?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to implement a Windows Application or extension? to enable iPad like scrolling System wide for all apps ?
The OSX equivalent would be SmartScroll:
www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html

Possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I found your question in elance.com. 
If you need those functions implemented in ALL Windows applications - the answer is NO. Some applications can be forced to scroll smoothly, but not all of them: applications can use custom objects to implement scroll bars. Actually, this task is possible for one (or few) selected apps, but you need to write some code and do testing for each application. For example: Logitech "Flow Scroll" software implements smooth scrolling in popular browsers, i have M325 mouse with this function. In other apps this software don't work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! So it is not possible to implement something like smartscroll but for Windows?

Comment: Possible, but not for all application. I check this Logitech "Flow Scroll" software - it's installed as plugin for browser, not as external application. Looks like this software don't use WinAPI message WM_MOUSEWHEEL, but move pages in some other way instead. I can do some tests, it's integersting, but you should select a targer software.

Comment: Ok lets start with the Windows Explorer. Its really a shame.

Comment: Done some tests. Well, i can say that... need more tests )

Comment: Explorer's scrollbar supports smooth scrolling for sure, but i still can't find a way to force it. WM_MOUSEMOVE works only if mouse button is pressed, and it performs a way to scroll smoothly. I'll perform some more tests.

Comment: Done more tests. Some results: Explorer's scroll bars does not respond to WM_VSCROLL with SB_THUMBTRACK flag, does not respond to sequence WM_LBUTTONDOWN + WM_MOUSEMOVE + WM_LBUTTONUP. But it responds to WM_MOUSEMOVE when left mouse button actually pressed anywhere on the screen. Looks like Explorer uses GetKeyState API. So, easy way don't work. There are one more way: inject dll to explorer.exe process, but it's complicated and takes too much time to check.